# Network Communication TCP [Code Design]

Tags: java, networking, tcp, udp

I've been messing a lot with TCP/IP Communication the last few days (Using Java and C#). I understand how it works and am able to use it. My Question is more a code design question, how its done the best and easy way to make a real communication.

For Example ive Built my own Multiuser Chat Server. I want my Communication to be able to decide wather its an Auth request, or a new chat message the ability to get the current user list etc etc.

Ive implemented a few ways on my own, but im not quite happy About that since i think theres a more standard and beauty way to do this.

My first thought was a String with Delimiters wich gets splitted, here is the Example of my Implementation of my Communication in Java:

```
//The Object-types im Using
clientSocket = new Socket(host, port_number);
_toServer = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
_fromServer = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

//Example Commands my Client sends to the server

_toServer.println("STATUS|"); //Gets the Status if server is online or closed (closed can occur when server runs but chat is disabled)
_toServer.println("AUTH|user|pw"); //Sends an auth Request to Server with username and Password
_toServer.println("MESSAGE|Hello World|ALL"); //Sends hello World in the Normal Chat to all Users
_toServer.println("MESSAGE|Hello World|PRIVATE|foo"); //Sends hello World only to the user "foo"
_toServer.println("USERS|GET"); //Request a list of all Connected Users


//Example In the Recieved Message Method where all The Server Messages Get Analyzed
serverMessage = _fromServer.readLine(); //Reads the Server Messages

String action = serverMessage.split("|")[0];

if (action.equals("USERS")) { //Example "USERS|2|foo;bar"
    String users[] = serverMessage.split("|")[2].split(";");
}
if (action.equals("MESSAGE")) { //Example "MESSAGE|Hello World|PRIVATE|foo"
    if(serverMessage.split("|")[2].equals("ALL") {
        //Code and else for private....
    }
}
if (serverMessage.equals("STATUS|ONLINE")) {
    // Code
    // I leave out //Code and } for the next If statements
}
if (serverMessage.equals("STATUS|OFFLINE")) {
if (serverMessage.equals("AUTH|ACCEPTED")) {
if (serverMessage.equals("AUTH|REJECT")) {
```

Is this the way its normally Done? Ad You See I need to send Statuscodes and Objects Corresponding to the Code. Ive Thought about Writing the Data in Bytes aswell and Implementing a "Decoder for Each Object", Example:

```
int action = _fromServer.readInt();     

//opcodes is just an Enum Holding the corresponding int

switch(action) {
  case(opcodes.MESSAGE):
    break;
  case(opcodes.AUTH):
    break;         
 }
```

Note that this is more over a general design Question not just for this Chat Server Example, I think im Implementing a little Network Based Console Game just for Practise.

Is there a better way to do this or even an API/Framework?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Essentially you're designing a protocol. There are a number of communication protocols that can handle this, the main one that comes to mind is IRC. I'm sure you can do a web search for tips on how to implement the protocol.

As for extending something like this for a console game, well I would start with implementing IRC, and using that to learn how real communication protocols are written. Once you've done that you can build on it to add your own commands to your framework.

Comment: Thanks for your fast Answer, Ive already messed with a few Games wich had a Documented Protocoll and those were always like my 2nd example, first 4/8 Bytes are action code, rest follows as data. I was hoping for Something existing like a interface to implement on Objects that gives the ability to transform em into such a protocoll form

Answer (score 2):

If you are designing a protocol for inter-language communication, I would suggest not to use formated Strings as a means of communication but statusbytes. If you consider for example the design of TCP/IP itself you will find, messages consist of a fixed-format header and a variable payload. That way you always know, that (e.g.) the third byte of the message contains the messagetype, the fifth denotes an errorstate and so on. This makes handling easier.

If you have designed your protocol, you could consider working with explicit MessageObjects on the java-side, in which case you would implement a factory with marshalling and unmarshalling methods for these objects, converting objects from and to messages in your protocol.

If you are all-java you can even spare that effort and use ObjectInputStreams and ObjectOutputStreams on client and Server. If you are not, you might want to take a look at the Google Protocol Buffers: http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/protocolbuffers/, which do essentially the same for inter-language communication.

Answer (score 2):

If your project grows, you may want to have a look at [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) - it's a framework for dealing with communication code. If your code is simple, you will be better off doing things manually.

As for protocol design, it depends on what is most important for you: performance, extensibility, human-readability, ease of debugging etc. These criteria may oppose each other to some degree, for example high performance may mean preference for binary protocols, but these negatively impact ease of debugging and sometimes extensibility. It's usually a good idea to not reinvent the wheel. Get inspired by existing protocols. If you choose to go binary, don't start from scratch unless you really have to, start with [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). If your app is simple and not aimed at very high performance, use a human-readable protocol which will make your life easier (debugging and testing are possible with standard shell tools such as `strace` and `nc`).

Answer (score 1):

I think Apache MINA will help you.  http://mina.apache.org/

Building a Java C/S application is really complex, you need to deal TCP, UDP and multi threads programming; MINA can help you for these things.

I think the other part you need is your private chatting protocol, but how about the open sourced IM service like Jabber? :)

Comment: Thanks for the MINA link ill have a look at it! It sounds as if thats what i've searched for. Im not planning on launching a Chat server, it is just for Practising and Understanding how a TCP communication in whatever Context should be done the right way. The Complex part for me is the Protocol